# Plotting how sunrise times change over the year

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, astronomy

I created a somewhat lengthy Python code to show how the time of sunrise varies over a year, resulting in the following figure (daylight savings were disregarded):

[image: sunrise vs. day]

The dataset can be found [here](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_rstablew.pl?ID=AA&year=2016&task=0&state=NJ&place=Trenton). The main difficulty was plotting the times correctly (659 should be adjacent to 700), and the subsequent labeling. My friend suggested without proof that this sort of diagram could be generated very easily (and perhaps more beautifully) in Mathematica and I was curious how one might go about it. My experience with plotting in Mathematica is very limited, but I'd be interested to learn!

Comment: Just look in the documentation under e.g., `Sunrise`... everything you need is there, including examples...

Comment: Searching google for "Mathematica Sunrise" leads you here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sunrise.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Importing and converting the data**

`Import` the data (replace `"path_to_the_downloaded_file.html"` with the file path of the actual data).

```
data = Import["path_to_the_downloaded_file.html", "Text"];
```

We know that our data of interest is formatted as `(4 digits)(whitespace)(4 digits)`, so we can extract that, extract time of sunrise from it, and convert the sunrise to minutes:

```
data = StringCases[data, a : Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}] ~~
     " " ~~ Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}] :> 
     Dot[FromDigits /@ StringPartition[a, 2], {60, 1}]];
```

The list is scrambled, so we need to unscramble that.

Fortunately, the input data has months as columns and days as rows. We can use that property.

First generate a list from 1 to 366 (2016 is a leap year!) and split them according to the length of each month.

```
days = Internal`PartitionRagged[
 Range[366], {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}];
```

Then we swap rows and columns (`Transpose` doesn't work here because the list is ragged. We need `Flatten`: see [(119)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/35945)):

```
days = Flatten[days, {2, 1}];
```

We then use the `data` and `days` to rearrange the `data` in the correct order:

```
data = Normal@SparseArray@Inner[Rule, days, data, List];
```

The above codes in one line:

```
data = Normal@SparseArray@
  Inner[Rule, 
   Flatten[Internal`PartitionRagged[
     Range[366], {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 
      31}], {2, 1}], 
   StringCases[Import["path_to_the_downloaded_file.html", "Text"], 
    a : Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}] ~~ " " ~~ 
      Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}] :> 
     Dot[FromDigits /@ StringPartition[a, 2], {60, 1}]], List];
```

**Constructing a plot**

*Mathematica* doesn't have an option to use time as the y-axis, so we use the `Ticks` option to manually set the tick marks. (see [(42528)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42529/35945) for details)

```
With[{ticks = Range[240, 450, 30], 
  toHrMin = DateString[{0, 0, 0, 0, #}, {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}] &}, 
 ListPlot[data, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Transpose@{ticks, toHrMin /@ ticks}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Day", "Sunrise"}]]
```

**Result!**

[image: Graph]

***Edit***

**Using the `Sunrise` Function**

```
data =
 Dot[#[{"Hour", "Minute"}], {60, 1}] & /@ 
  Normal[Sunrise[
     Entity["City", {"Trenton", "NewJersey", "UnitedStates"}], 
     DateRange[{2016, 1, 1}, {2016, 12, 31}, {1, "Day"}], 
     TimeZone -> -5]][[All, -1]];

(* Same code as above *)
With[{ticks = Range[240, 450, 30], 
  toHrMin = DateString[{0, 0, 0, 0, #}, {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}] &}, 
 ListPlot[data, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Transpose@{ticks, toHrMin /@ ticks}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Day", "Sunrise"}]]
```

[image: Graph from Sunrise]

Note: for an unknown reason, the output of the `Sunrise` function (which is downloaded from Wolfram database) is not consistent with the data in OP.

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent! Even if there is in fact a `Sunrise` function it's nice to see how one would parse and plot the data in more general cases.