# Daylight hours vs calendar date

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, wolfram-alpha-queries

Is there a way in Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha to get a plot of daylight hours vs calendar date and rate of change of daylight hours vs calendar date. Lets say I want the plot for latitude 45 degrees north?

Comment: Like this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124903/plotting-how-sunrise-times-change-over-the-year?

Comment: should also have wolfram-alpha-query tag but I don't know how to add an additional tag.

Comment: Here's how I did it: https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-visualization/daily-dose-of-sunshine.html

Answer (score 2):

As Brett's example that he linked to in his comment shows, this can be easily done using the `Sunrise` and `Sunset` functions:

```
days = DateRange[{2019, 1, 1}, {2019, 12, 31}, "Day"];
daylightHours = QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[Sunrise[#], Sunset[#], "Hour"] & /@ days;
DateListPlot@Transpose[{days, daylightHours}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The rate of change can be approximated by:

```
DateListPlot@Transpose[{Most[days], Differences@daylightHours}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a bonus, [this page](http://www.jgiesen.de/astro/solarday.htm) shows how to estimate the daylight time based on the sun's altitude, which is available through `SunPosition`:

```
gothenburg = Entity["City",{"Goteborg","VastraGotaland","Sweden"}];
latitude = gothenburg["Latitude"];
{azimuth,altitude} = SunPosition[gothenburg];

daysSinceVernalEquinox = QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[
    DateObject[{2019, 3, 21}],
    DateObject[],
    "Days"
    ];

declination = Quantity[23.5 Sin[(daysSinceVernalEquinox/365) 365 Degree], "Degree"];
localHourAngle = ArcCos[-Tan[latitude] Tan[declination]]/Degree;
daylight = 2 Quantity[24, "Hours"] (localHourAngle/360)
```

> 11.5259

The corresponding value obtained using `Sunrise` and `Sunset`:

```
DateDifference[Sunset[gothenburg], Sunrise[gothenburg], "Hour"]
```

> 11.7667

Comment: That's fabulous, thank you. Note that in the 'daylightHours =  " line it should be "Hour" ;  "Hours" resulted in an error on my system running Mathematica 11.0.1.

Comment: @LA_Ross Thanks, that's good to know. "Hours" works in Mathematica 12, but edited for better compatibility.